# populating the data in the form once typed in without saving to database with Grails

Tags: grails

I have created login authentication without using Spring Security. I would like use session such that once entered fields in form (on refresh as well) remains through out the session without saving in database. How should I achieve that using session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.2.1/ref/Servlet%20API/session.html

Alternatively, you could use cookies or HTML5 local storage.

Comment: Thank you! I am  using grails session, and able to access user through out session,but when I enter values from gsp for another domains how should I save it for session scope without saving to database, I tried with def inBasic=session["InBasic"]  but no use.

Comment: You shouldn't use domain classes as data objects. So instead of using domain classes use POGOs.